# Identify origin of variable in namespace

Tags: r

I need to change the definition of a variable that is contained in the namespace of the package I am working with, but I cannot find the definition anywhere. I can identify it like this

```
> library("MyPackage")
> getAnywhere(MyVariable)
A single object matching ‘MyVariable’ was found
It was found in the following places
  namespace:MyPackage
with value ...
```

I can also see it when I run

```
> env = asNamespace("MyPackage")
> ls(envir = env)
```

However, it is not contained in the NAMESPACE file of the project folder.
So I am wondering, if it is not contained in the NAMESPACE file, where can it possibly come from? Could it come from another package, even though getAnywhere() links to MyPackage? In that case, should I be able to see it in the NAMESPACE file from that package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NAMESPACE` file is for imports and exports. If a variable isn't exported by the package (i.e. it is an internal variable that they don't really want you to use), it won't be in there.

`MyVariable` could have come from anywhere in the package.

If you want to access it, use `:::`. `:::` can access unexported variables whereas `::` only accesses exported variables.

```
MyPackage:::MyVariable
```

If you want to modify it, use `assignInNamespace`

```
assignInNamespace("MyVariable", "NEW VALUE", ns = "MyPackage")
```

Comment: Hi Paul. Thanks a lot for your answer. I will try this. The function assignInNamespace looks very promising.
I am wondering, do you happen to know if there is a function to also rename or delete a variable in the namespace?

Comment: When loading packages with `library`, the package's environment is locked.

See `?bindenv`: `Locking the environment prevents adding or removing variable bindings from the environment.`

Once an environment is locked it normally cannot be unlocked.